# Stored procedures with Delphi and dbExpress

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, parameters, dbexpress

I wish to execute the Sybase stored procedure `sp_helpdb` with a `dbname` as parameter. Here is my code

```
  with SQLStoredProc1 do
    begin
      StoredProcName := 'sp_helpdb';
      PrepareStatement;
      ParamByName('dbname').Value := 'MyDb';
      Open;
      ...
```

The line `ParamByName...` throws an exception with message

> Parameter 'dbname' not found

If I use

```
Params[0].AsString := 'MyDb';
```

instead, the exception message is

> List index out of bound(0)

Could you tell me what's wrong?

And second question: suppose it works, how can I get the result, as it looks like a mix of two recordsets

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to provide the schema for the "sp_helpdb" procedure, for example: In MSSQL there is a equivalent sp_help, that is located at sys schema. Therefore, in schemaname property I need to enter with 'sys'.

Comment: Yes, Matheus; I've seen in sereral examples, that schema property was filled. I've no idea what is the schema for sp_helpdb but i will have a look 
Thank's a lot

Comment: Have you tried "sys"?

Comment: I was quite busy this afternoon so I'll try tomorrow and I'll post the result. Thank's to worry

Comment: Matheus, "sys" doesn't work. I'll ask to a colleague who is specialist of Sybase. I hope he'll have an idea